# Pester Test for scriptproperty return type

Tags: powershell, pester

I am new to pester and trying to create tests for PowerShell class modules. I am trying to determine how to test for my particular method of implementing properties for my classes.

The basic structure that I use is:

```
class TestClass {
    hidden [string] $_TestProp = $($this | Add-Member -MemberType ScriptProperty -Name TestProp -Value {
            return $this._TestProp
        } -SecondValue {
            param([string]$Value)
            $this._TestProp = $Value
        }
    )
}
```

This structure, while more work, does allow me the ability to use what I deem "normal" getter\setter functionality within my classes. What I am trying to test is making sure that this property is of type string. I've attempted to try and view the AST for the Getter script block but I wasn't able to find the return type of the scriptblock.

Does anyone have any ideas as to how I would test for the return type of a scriptblock?

**Update**

As per a suggestion in the comments, I have rewritten the class as such

```
class TestClass {
    hidden [string] $_TestProp 

    TestClass(){
        $this | Add-Member -MemberType ScriptProperty -Name TestProp -Value {
            return $this._TestProp
        } -SecondValue {
            param([string]$Value)
            $this._TestProp = $Value
        }
    }
}
```

Functionally it is still the same the add member section was just moved to the constructor area instead of the declaration.

Comment: You won't get any coverage stats of value by using that pattern as no reporter could untangle that particular pattern; too much magic.  Is there a reason you're going that route for a property instead of just using methods or implementing it via `Add-Type` and writing `c#` which will be more concise?

Comment: Please, for the love of your CPU, move the `Add-Member` statement to the constructor!

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen You make a valid point. This pattern was something that I picked up a couple of years ago when I was trying to achieve a specific goal since accessors and mutators are not native to PowerShell classes. Since I've never experienced any performance-related issues, I've never really considered optimizing it. Based on your comments, I have updated my pattern accordingly

Comment: @MaximilianBurszley My C# skills are a bit out of date and the question only pertains to a small portion of a much larger project. rewriting all of the classes in the project in C# is beyond the scope at the moment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After doing some additional research I was able to come up with the following method of getting the information I was looking for

```
$Instance = [TestClass]::new()
$PropName = "TestProp"
$PublicProp = $Instance.PSObject.Properties | Where-Object {$_.Name -eq "$($PropName)"}
$BackingProp = $Instance.PSObject.Properties["_$($PropName)"]
$BackingProp.TypeNameOfValue -eq $PublicProp.SetterScript.Ast.ParamBlock.Parameters.StaticType.FullName
```

This ensures that the Setter value being passed in is the same type as the backing property

Answer (score -1):

ScriptBlocks don’t have a type signature like, say, methods in C# do, so the only way you can really determine the return type is by Invoking it and seeing what you get back.

Even then, the return type might change between calls. For example, what is the return type of the script block below?

```
$myScriptBlock = {
    if( (Get-Random -Maximum 2) -gt 0 )
    {
        return 100;
    }
    else
    {
        return "aaa";
    }
}
```

The formal definition of ScriptBlock.Invoke says it returns a `Collection<PSObject>` here - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.management.automation.scriptblock.invoke?view=pscore-6.2.0 - so you *could* say that’s the return type, but that doesn’t really help you do static analysis of the AST to determine whether that collection contains a single string value or something else for a specific script block...

Comment: Please see my suggested answer

Comment: Scriptblocks are just anonymous functions.  You can typecast them just like any other object using `Func<T, R>` or `Action<T, R>`.